# Join two dataframes to get data into another dataframe and create a new column in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe

```
mail_id         e_no
aaa@ven.com     111
bbb@ven.com     222
ccc@ven.com     333
```

I have another dataframe

```
email           emp_no
aaa@ven.com     111
                222
                333
```

I need to fill the emp_no from second dataframe using first dataframe.
I need to do a left join to get all records from first dataframe.
I also need an extra col to indicate from which dataframe I'm getting the emp_no.

The final dataframe should be like:

```
email           emp_no  src
aaa@ven.com     111     tbl1
bbb@ven.com     222     tbl2
ccc@ven.com     333     tbl2
```

```
final_df = df1.join(df2, df1['e_no'] == df2['emp_no'], 'left')
final_df = final_df.withColumn('src', F.when('mail_id'.isNull() | mail_id =='', 'tbl2')
                                        .when('mail_id' != '', 'tbl1')
                                        .otherwise(F.lit('')))
```

I'm not getting the right results. Please suggest if any changes are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# Performing left join
result = df1.join(df2, df1.mail_id == df2.email, "left")

# Creating the 'src' column
result = result.withColumn("src", when(col("emp_no").isNull(), "tbl1").otherwise("tbl2"))

# Selecting and renaming columns to match the final desired format
final_result = result.select(
    col("mail_id").alias("email"),
    when(col("emp_no").isNull(), col("e_no")).otherwise(col("emp_no")).alias("emp_no"),
    "src"
)

final_result.show()
```